# you can't present Sheet in child View in SwiftUI if there is already a sheet in parent view

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

Is it possible to present sheet in a child view in SwiftUI that already has a Sheet in its parent view ?

```
struct SheetTest: View {
    @State var showFirstSheet = false
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("FirstView")
                .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                    showFirstSheet = true
                })
            SomeView()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showFirstSheet, content: {
            Text("firstsheet")
        })
            
    }
}
struct SomeView:View {
    @State var showSecondSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("SecondView")
            .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                showSecondSheet = true
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondSheet, content: {
                Text("secondsheet")
            })
    }
}
```

I am currently using Xcode 12 beta 3!
and second sheet can't be presented this way!
I have to present it in the parent view!

Comment: Yes, you can't. Known issue. The same for .alert. Submit feedback to Apple - the more submitted the better.

Comment: thanks! I will submit it

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to be careful not to add `.sheet` to the same view tree.
I'm using `Xcode 12.1 (12A7403)` .

```swift
struct SheetTest: View {
    @State var showFirstSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("FirstView")
                .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                    showFirstSheet = true
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showFirstSheet, content: {
                    Text("firstsheet")
                })
            SomeView()
        }
    }
}
struct SomeView:View {
    @State var showSecondSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("SecondView")
            .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                showSecondSheet = true
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondSheet, content: {
                Text("secondsheet")
            })
    }
}
```